# In an iframe, build url from parent page hostname and new params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, cross-domain

I have two sites which communicate with each other.  I'll call them mainsite.com and backend.com for this example.

mainsite.com is the site that people go to, and this loads an iframe which loads in backend.com, which is a Rails site that handles all of the login & signup stuff.  At the end of the login process, backend.com generates a url which has an encrypted set of params which are used to log the user into mainsite.com.

The way that this is currently working is that backend.com controller generates a url like this "http://mainsite.com?auth=2347qweiuyqi" and saves it in a variable called @redirect_url, then (in the iframe) renders out some html which contains some javascript to redirect the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){   
    window.top.location.href = "<%= @redirect_url %>"; 
  });
</script>
```

This is working fine.  However, we have a new situation where people can now access mainsite.com via a load of different urls (all subdomains on other sites, like mainsite.foo.com and mainsite.bar.com)

Now, when i redirect them to the auth url on mainsite, i want them to stay on whichever domain they're on.  So, if they're on `mainsite.foo.com`, and loading `backend.com` in the iframe, then at the end of the login process i want to redirect the parent window to `mainsite.foo.com?auth=2347qweiuyqi`.  Similarly, if they're on `mainsite.bar.com` they should be redirected to `mainsite.bar.com?auth=2347qweiuyqi`

My initial attempt at this was to change the javascript to get the domain name from the parent window, and build the redirect url by adding the params onto the end, then redirecting to this url.  However, the iframe can't access the parent domain name because of cross-domain protection (ie the domains, "mainsite.foo.com", and "backend.com", don't match.

My next attempt was to have a javascript function on mainsite.com which takes the auth param and redirects to a url consisting of the current domain with that param added onto the end.  But, i can't call a parent window function because of the same cross-domain restrictions.

How can I get past this?  I have complete control over the content of both sites.

One solution which i know would work, but is a bit of hassle to set up, is to pass through the mainsite domain name through as a parameter in the src attribute of the iframe to backend.com, and then make sure that backend.com hangs on to that through the whole login/signup process, so that at the end of the process it can use it to build the whole url to redirect to.  But, it feels like there should be a simpler way.

thanks, Max

EDIT - i've solved this by, when the first request comes through from `mainsite.com` to `backend.com`, saving the hostname of request.referer into the session, and then, later on when i come to do the redirect, looking it up from the session and adding the auth params on.  This works but it feels a bit unsatisfactory so i'm interested in nicer solutions.